# Read-only variable is not assignable

Tags: c++

Yes this is for homework, my code is asking me to enter an array that is terminated upon typing in the number 0 or when it reaches the maximum number of integers `ARRAY_SIZE` so when I type in my code the line `array[num_elements]=i;` returns an error that states `Read-only variable is not assignable`.

```
void read_list(const int array[], int & num_elements) {
    int i(1);

    cout<<"Enter list of "<< ARRAY_SIZE<<" integers (ending with 0)";

    while (i != 0 && num_elements < ARRAY_SIZE) {
        cin >> i;
        array[num_elements] = i;
num_elements++;
    }

}
```

Comment: @xd6_ No, num_elements is not a pointer. The error comes from the fact that `array` is declared const.

Comment: Just remove const qualifier from the `array` variable.

Comment: The value that is printed should be `ARRAY_SIZE - num_elements - 1` instead of `ARRAY_SIZE`.

Comment: An other issue: the value of `array` is never returned. You might want to pass that as a reference.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, your use of `num_elements` is a bit puzzling. The way it's written, nothing will be assinged to array[0] - array[num_elements-1].

Comment: @RSahu: I think that is on purpose. If array is passed as a reference instead, that would allow calling read_list multiple times... even though it would be fully filled the first time, so the following times nothing would happen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, your array's fields are read-only variables, so you can't assign values to them.

Remove the `const` qualifier, and it should work fine.

I'm unsure whether `array[num_elements] = num_elements++` does something useful, though.
Maybe you wanted to do `array[num_elements++] = i` instead?

Answer (score 1):

You are using constant reference to access elements of the array. You may not assign these elements using a constant reference. So you need to remove qualifier const from the parameter declaration.

Also the code of the function is wrong.
For example it does initialize num_elements and assigns 0 to the last element of the array.

The function should look the following way

```
int read_list( int array[], int max_size ) 
{
    int i = 0;
    int x;

    std::cout<<"Enter list of no more than " << max_size << " integers (0 - exit): ";

    while ( i < max_size && std::cin >> x && x != 0 ) 
    {
        array[i++] = x;
    }

    return i;
}
```

And it can be called as

```
int num_elements = read_list( YourArray, ARRAY_SIZE );
```